# Bourne shell function return variable always empty

Tags: function, shell, return-value, sh

The following Bourne shell script, given a path, is supposed to test each component of the path for existence; then set a variable comprising only those components that actually exist.

```
#! /bin/sh
set -x             # for debugging

test_path() {
  path=""
  echo $1 | tr ':' '\012' | while read component
  do
    if [ -d "$component" ]
    then
      if [ -z "$path" ]
      then path="$component"
      else path="$path:$component"
      fi
    fi
  done
  echo "$path"    # this prints nothing
}

paths=/usr/share/man:\
/usr/X11R6/man:\
/usr/local/man

MANPATH=`test_path $paths`
echo $MANPATH
```

When run, it always prints nothing.  The trace using `set -x` is:

```
+ paths=/usr/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/usr/local/man
++ test_path /usr/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/usr/local/man
++ path=
++ echo /usr/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/usr/local/man
++ tr : '\012'
++ read component
++ '[' -d /usr/share/man ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ path=/usr/share/man
++ read component
++ '[' -d /usr/X11R6/man ']'
++ read component
++ '[' -d /usr/local/man ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/man ']'
++ path=/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man
++ read component
++ echo ''
+ MANPATH=
+ echo
```

Why is the final `echo $path` empty?  The `$path` variable within the `while` loop was incrementally set for each iteration just fine.

Comment: `/bin/sh` typically just means a POSIX-compliant shell, which is not necessarily (or even usually) an actual Bourne shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe runs all commands involved in sub-shells, including the entire `while ...` loop. Therefore, all changes to variables in that loop are confined to the sub-shell and invisible to the parent shell script.

One way to work around that is putting the `while ...` loop and the `echo` into a list that executes entirely in the sub-shell, so that the modified variable `$path` is visible to `echo`:

```
test_path()
{
  echo "$1" | tr ':' '\n' | {
  while read component
    do
      if [ -d "$component" ]
      then
        if [ -z "$path" ]
        then
          path="$component"
        else
          path="$path:$component"
        fi
      fi
    done
    echo "$path"
  }
}
```

However, I suggest using something like this:

```
test_path()
{
    echo "$1" | tr ':' '\n' |
    while read dir
    do
        [ -d "$dir" ] && printf "%s:" "$dir"
    done |
    sed 's/:$/\n/'
}
```

... but that's a matter of taste.

**Edit:** As others have said, the behaviour you are observing depends on the shell. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) describes pipelined commands as run in sub-shells, but that is not a requirement:

> Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment; as an extension, however, any or all commands in a pipeline may be executed in the current environment.

Bash runs them in sub-shells, but some shells run the last command in the context of the main script, when only the preceding commands in the pipeline are run in sub-shells.

Comment: Is there any way to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This should work in a Bourne shell that understands functions (and would work in Bash and other shells too):

```
test_path() {
  echo $1 | tr ':' '\012' |
  {
  path=""
  while read component
  do
    if [ -d "$component" ]
    then
      if [ -z "$path" ]
      then path="$component"
      else path="$path:$component"
      fi
    fi
  done
  echo "$path"    # this prints nothing
  }
}
```

The inner set of braces groups the commands into a unit, so `path` is only set in the subshell but is echoed from the same subshell.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the final echo $path empty?

Until recently, Bash would give all components of a pipeline their own process, separate from the shell process in which the pipeline is run.
Separate process == separate address space, and no variable sharing.

In ksh93 and in recent Bash (may need a shopt setting), the shell will run the *last* component of a pipeline in the calling shell, so any variables changed inside the loop are preserved when the loop exits.

Another way to accomplish what you want is to make sure that the `echo $path` is in the same process as the loop, using parentheses:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -x             # for debugging

test_path() {
  path=""
  echo $1 | tr ':' '\012' | ( while read component
  do
    [ -d "$component" ] || continue

    path="${path:+$path:}$component"
  done
  echo "$path"
  )
}
```

Note: I simplified the inner `if`.  There was no `else` so the test can  be replaced with a shortcut.  Also, the two path assignments can be combined into one, using the `S{var:+ ...}` parameter substitution trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works just fine with no change under Solaris 11 and probably also most commercial Unix like AIX and HP-UX because under these OSes, the underlying implementation of `/bin/sh` is provided by `ksh`. This would be also the case if `/bin/sh` is backed by `zsh`.

It doesn't work for you likely because your `/bin/sh` is implemented by one of `bash`, `dash`, `mksh` or `busybox sh` which all process each component of a pipeline in a subshell while `ksh` and `zsh` both keep the last element of a pipeline in the current shell, saving an unnecessary fork.

It is possible to "fix" your script for it to work when `sh` is provided by bash by adding this line somewhere before the pipeline:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

or better, if you wan't to keep portability:

```
command -v shopt > /dev/null && shopt -s lastpipe
```

This will keep the script working for `ksh`, and `zsh` but still won't work for `dash`, `mksh` or the original Bourne shell.

Note that both `bash` and `ksh` behaviors are allowed by the POSIX standard.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about the `lastpipe` option in bash. Thanks for the pointer. This may allow some simplifications in bash scripts.